# Transforming a really large integer in Symbian descriptor-form to an unsigned char*

Tags: c++, c, symbian, rsa

We're trying to implement RSA encryption in Symbian using the Open C/C++ library (rsa.h), and the 'RSA_public_encrypt' method:

`buffSize = RSA_public_encrypt(maxSize, (unsigned char *) plainkey, (unsigned char *) cipherkey, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);`

We created a public key with our own exponent and modulus and put that in the 'rsa'-object.
Our plain text to be encrypted is a very large integer received in string form (so as a Symbian descriptor).

However, the plain text should be provided as an 'unsigned char*' to the encryption method.
How can I transform the descriptor (plain text) to an 'unsigned char*' so that the encryption method interprets our plain text as a very large integer.
Or for those not familiar with Symbian descriptors: how can I transform the plain text from a regular string (char *) to a value that the encryption interprets as a very large integer.

We already tried to provide the plain text in several ways, but the encryption text wasn't what it should have been 
(we compared this with results on other platforms which we verified was correct).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: unsigned char * IS plain text. Please post an example of how you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate (malloc) the plainkey and cipherkey variables and copy the unencrypted plain text string to cipherkey using lstrcpy or something similar in order to make this function work.

```
plainkey = malloc(PLAINKEY_SIZE);
cipherkey = malloc(CIPHERKEY_SIZE);
lstrcpy(plainkey, "12345...");
buffSize = RSA_public_encrypt(maxSize, plainkey, cipherkey, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);
```

you can also use unsigned char arrays:

```
unsigned char plainkey[PLAINKEY_SIZE] = "12345...";
unsigned char plainkey[CIPHERKEY_SIZE];
buffSize = RSA_public_encrypt(maxSize, plainkey, cipherkey, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

I tried your suggestions but got the same (wrong) result as I got before. So the problem should lie elsewhere. If anyone knows about RSA encryption with openSSL, please check my other thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817334/openssl-rsa-encryption-with-no-padding-fails-to-encrypt-correctly), maybe you can spot a mistake there. Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `RSA_public_encrypt` is `flen` and the second is `from` i.e. it will encrypt `flen` bytess from `from`.

Assuming you have a `TDesC8` descriptor `source` you want to encrypt, call the function like this:

```
 RSA_public_encrypt(source.Length(), source.Ptr(), ...
```